# How do I make all the calculations in double precision in fortran?

Tags: fortran, fortran90, gfortran

In the Fortran code given below, I have made all numbers involving calculation of PI as double precision but the value of PI I get is just a real number with a large number of zero or 9 at the end. How do I make the program give PI in double precision? I am using `gfortran` compiler.

```
  !This program determines the value of pi using Monte-Carlo algorithm.
  program findpi
  implicit none
  double precision :: x,y,radius,truepi,cnt
  double precision,allocatable,dimension(:) :: pi,errpi
  integer :: seedsize,i,t,iter,j,k,n
  integer,allocatable,dimension(:) :: seed

  !Determining the true value of pi to compare with the calculated value
  truepi=4.D0*ATAN(1.D0)

  call random_seed(size=seedsize)
  allocate(seed(seedsize))
  do i=1,seedsize
     call system_clock(t) !Using system clock to randomise the seed to 
                          !random number generator
     seed(i)=t
  enddo
  call random_seed(put=seed)

  n=2000         !Number of times value of pi is determined
  allocate(pi(n),errpi(n))
  do j=1,n
     iter=n*100  !Number of random points
     cnt=0.D0
     do i=1,iter
        call random_number(x)
        call random_number(y)
        radius=sqrt(x*x + y*y)
        if (radius < 1) then
           cnt = cnt+1.D0
        endif
     enddo
     pi(j)=(4.D0*cnt)/dble(iter)
     print*, j,pi(j)
  enddo

  open(10,file="pi.dat",status="replace")
  write(10,"(F15.8,I10)") (pi(k),k,k=1,n)

  call system("gnuplot --persist piplot.gnuplot")

end program findpi
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your calculation is in double precision, but I see two issues:

- The first is a systematic error... You determine pi by

```
pi(j)=(4.D0*cnt)/dble(iter)
```

`iter` is at most 2000*100, so `1/iter` is at least `5e-6`, so you can't resolve anything finder than that ;-)

- The second issue is that your IO routines print the results in single precision! The line

```
write(10,"(F15.8,I10)") (pi(k),k,k=1,n)
```

and more specifically the format specifier `"(F15.8,I10)"` needs to be adjusted. At the moment it tells the compiler to use 15 characters overall to print the number, with 8 digits after the decimal point. As a first measure, you could use `*`:

```
write(10,*) (pi(k),k,k=1,n)
```

This uses 22 characters in total with all 15 digits for double precision:

```
write(10,"(F22.15,I10)") (pi(k),k,k=1,n)
```